# Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications

Tags: visual-studio, firefox, iis, blazor

I try to debug my application. It has some problems with rendering in Firefox. When I try to run it locally works perfectly fine on Chrome, Edge and IE but when I use Firefox at the moment when I press **Sign In** button (goes to Azure) I get the error below.

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request.
>
> Request ID: |17bfbb4c-4c6df100ef98c952. Development Mode
>
> Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed
>   information about the error that occurred.
>
> Development environment should not be enabled in deployed
>   applications, as it can result in sensitive information from
>   exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging,
>   development environment can be enabled by setting the
>   ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and
>   restarting the application.

I checked the project settings and variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` has `Development` value. I restarted VS and also  removed the value, rebuild and added again - didn't help.

In similar questions I found that can be covering some errors - in my case everything works fine on other browsers.

Comment: You should firstly tell us where you hosted your application now? On IIS or visual stuido's debug mode. If you use VS debug mode, I suggest you cou could add breakpoint to test. If you hosted the application on  the IIS, I suggest you could check the stdoutLogFile or the server's event viewer.